# CGAffineTransformScale scales imageview,but its sub elements on redrawing got blurred

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I am simply using this code to transform imageView to scale double or triple.

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scale, scale);
```

I am drawing lines on this imageView in drawRect,after scaling everything got scaled. What i want is those lines which i am drawing should remain of same size or width after scaling.In order to do that ,i am redrawing lines on scaled imageView with proportional less height and width but result is like lines got blurred/shady.I think on transforming the pixels size also got increase of imageView..I want to know is there any way to draw proper lines without any blurred effect on transformed imageView etc..

Answer (score 0):

Draw the lines AFTER you scale the image. Just change the width of the line to be the same scale (ie image is 4x, line width is 4x).